# Python Tkinter: how to reopen application by clicking Dock icon on Mac?

Tags: python, tkinter

I bind the close button with root.withdraw(), so the application will close its window instead of quitting, but seems the application hangs on, and cannot be reopened by clicking Dock icon

How to bind the method root.deiconify() to do this?

I package the application with pyinstaller

Update:
The python tkinter application seems hanging on after run root.iconify() or root.withdraw(), so there is no respond by clicking the icon on Dock. Here is the test code

```
from Tkinter import *
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText
import threading, time, os

def printnumber(output):
    n = 1
    while 1:
        output.insert(END, '%s\n'%str(n))
        output.see(END)
        n += 1
        time.sleep(1)

def runing(output):
    output.insert(END, 'Start\n')
    output.see(END)
    threading.Thread(target=printnumber, args=(output, )).start()

root = Tk()
text_output = ScrolledText(root, undo=1, highlightthickness=0, font='system', )
text_output.pack()
Button(root, text='Start', command=runing(text_output)).pack()
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda :root.iconify())
os.system('''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to set frontmost of every process whose unix id is %s to true' '''%os.getpid())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was wrong, it is active when minimized, but still do not know how to bind root.deiconify()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution from here http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html

```
root.createcommand('tk::mac::ReopenApplication', root.deiconify)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OS X 10.9 or later and a Python from a python.org 64-bit/32-bit installer, application windows may not update properly due to a Tk problem. Install the latest ActiveTcl 8.5.18.0 if possible. (Also, a critical OS X 10.9 problem that could cause Python to crash when used interactively has been fixed as of the 3.4.0, 3.3.3, and 2.7.6 installers.)

- That was taken from this link https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

There is a whole section Talking about different problems with Tk/IDLE depending on what version of OS X you're using.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later

Comment: It did work for me. I can not find any way to reactive the python tkinter app after running root.withdraw() or root.iconify() by click the icon on Dock.

Comment: Fixed by using root.createcommand('tk::mac::ReopenApplication', root.deiconify)